# Multiple case statements not working out

Tags: sql, postgresql, nested, case

I'm trying to add following logic to my code (it's huge and works without this so must be something wrong with below code) but I'm getting an error. I would suspect that something is wrong with END but logically thinking all 3 should be at the end so I'm not sure

```
case
    when t0."Final Sale Price" is null
      then null
    else case
      when t1."Fee" is not null
      and t0."Final Sale Price" >= t1."Guaranteed Price"
        then t1."Fee"
      else case
        when t1."Fee" is not null
        and t0."Final Sale Price" <= t1."Guaranteed Price"
          then t1."Fee" - (t1."Guaranteed Price" - t0."Final Sale Price")
        else case
          when t0."Final Sale Price" < t1."Guaranteed Price"
            then t0."Final Sale Price" - t1."Guaranteed Price"
          else(
            (
              (t0."Final Sale Price" - t1."Guaranteed Price") * (100 - t1."Seller Upside %")
            )
            / 100
          )
        end
      end
    end as "Actual Revenue"
```

Comment: I count four cases, but only three ends

Comment: And I can only find case expressions, not one single case statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
case 
when t0."Final Sale Price" is null then null
when t1."Fee" is not null then 
     case when t0."Final Sale Price" >= t1."Guaranteed Price" then t1."Fee" 
          when t0."Final Sale Price" < t1."Guaranteed Price" then t1."Fee" - (t1."Guaranteed Price" - t0."Final Sale Price")
     end
when t0."Final Sale Price" < t1."Guaranteed Price" then t0."Final Sale Price" - t1."Guaranteed Price"
else ((t0."Final Sale Price" - t1."Guaranteed Price") * (100 - t1."Seller Upside %")) / 100
end as "Actual Revenue"
```

The expression can be simplified as above.

Also note the question has 2 conditions,

`t0."Final Sale Price" >= t1."Guaranteed Price"`

and

`t0."Final Sale Price" <= t1."Guaranteed Price"`

final sale price = guaranteed price in both the conditions. If the first turns out to be true, the second condition won't be evaluated when they are equal. Make sure the `=` is specified only once, according to the output you expect from the `case` expression.

Answer (score 1):

There is generally no need to nest `case` statements:

```
select (case when t0."Final Sale Price" is null
             then null
             when t1."Fee" is not null and t0."Final Sale Price" >= t1."Guaranteed Price"
             then t1."Fee"
             when t1."Fee" is not null and t0."Final Sale Price" <= t1."Guaranteed Price"
             then t1."Fee" - (t1."Guaranteed Price" - t0."Final Sale Price")
             when t0."Final Sale Price" < t1."Guaranteed Price"
             then t0."Final Sale Price" - t1."Guaranteed Price"
             else (t0."Final Sale Price" - t1."Guaranteed Price") * (100 - t1."Seller Upside %") / 100
          )
       end) as "Actual Revenue"
```